# How to disable auto commit feature though bat file in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, shell, batch-file, autocommit

I  m calling PostgreSQL function in bat file want disable auto commit in bat file and commit inside function.

I need disable auto commit in bat file while calling PostgreSQL function

```
set PGPASSWORD=%PASSWORD%
  set AUTOCOMMIT=off
 PostgreSQL\\10\\bin\\psql.exe -h localhost  -U % postgres -d postgres  -c "SELECT public.deleteDatafromcsv();"
//Want add auto commit off here ??
```

Comment: That is pointless. This is a database session with a single statement. If you disable autocommit, the effects of the function will be rolled back when the session terminates. Pleas explain your [real problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).

Comment: deleteDatafromcsv have huge amount of data to delete need to commit on batch process that why I need disable auto commit

Comment: You cannot commit inside a function. Just perform the huge delete in a single transaction, that's not a problem in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thank I have question if auto commit by default on if my delete operation having some exception should it rollback or commit till time

Comment: If there is any error during a transaction, the whole transaction will be undone.